# How to store data with a tree-like structure in Julia

Tags: arrays, object, julia

I want to store high-frequency financial data in memory while I work with it in Julia.

My data is in lots of arrays of Float64. Each array stores high frequency data from a single day, for some security, on some market. For example, for the date 2010-01-04, for IBM, listed on the NYSE (New York Stock Exchange), there is one array of Float64.

As stated, I have many such arrays, spanning multiple dates, markets, and securities. I want to store them all in one object, such that it is easy to retrieve any given array (probably exploiting the tree-like structure of metadata).

In Matlab, I used to store this in a structure, where the first level is market, next level is security, next level is date, and then at the end of tree is the corresponding array. At each level I also stored a list of fields at that level.

[Julia doesn't really have an equivalent to Matlab structures](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/1263), so what is the best way to do this in Julia?

Currently, the best I can come up with is a sequence of nested composite types, each with two fields. For example:

```
type HighFrequencyData
    dateList::Array{Date, 1}
    dataArray::Array{Any, 1}
end
```

where `dateList` stores a list of dates that correspond to a sequence of arrays of Float64 held in `dataArray` (i.e. `dateList` and `dataArray` will have the same length). Then:

```
type securitiesData
    securityList::Array{String, 1}
    highFrequencyArray::Array{Any, 1}
end
```

where `securityList` stores a list of securities that correspond to a sequence of type `HighFrequencyData` held in `highFrequencyArray`. Then:

```
type marketsData
    marketList::Array{String, 1}
    securitiesArray::Array{Any, 1}
end
```

where `marketList` stores a list of markets that correspond to a sequence of type `securitiesData` held in `securitiesArray`.

Given this, all data can now be stored in a variable of type `marketsData`, and looked up using `marketList`, `securityList`, and `dateList`, at each level of nesting.

But this feels a bit cumbersome...

Comment: If anyone is interested, I ended up writing a package called `SortedStructures` to solve this problem. I ended up being able to do everything I wanted by building type aliases on the base types in that package. I haven't added it to `metadata`, but the source is [here on github](https://github.com/colintbowers/SortedStructures.jl)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your type hierarchy looks ok, but maybe dictionaries are all you need?

```
all_data = ["Market1" => {
             ["Sec1" => {[20140827, 20140825], [1.05, 10.6]}],
             ["Sec2" => {[20140827, 20140825], [1.05, 10.6]}]},
            "Market2" => {
             ["Sec1" => {[20140827, 20140825], [1.05, 10.6]}],
             ["Sec2" => {[20140827, 20140825], [1.05, 10.6]}]},
            ...]

println(all_data["Market1"]["Sec1"] ./ all_data["Market2"]["Sec1"])
```

If you could post what the MATLAB code looks like that might be helpful too.

I would reformulate your types a little bit, maybe something simpler like

```
type TimeSeries
    dates::Vector{Date}
    data::Vector{Any}
end

typealias Security (String,TimeSeries)
typealias Market Vector{Security}

markets = Market[]

push!(markets, [("Sec1",TimeSeries(...)), ("Sec2",TimeSeries(...)])
```

Also, make sure to check out https://github.com/JuliaStats/TimeSeries.jl

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you +1. I'll give it another 48 hours in case anyone else wants to respond, and then give the tick. Regarding the Matlab code, there isn't much to speak of. I would simply allocate an array to the structure using `structure.NYSE.IBM.D2010-01-04.data = myArray` (repeat for all arrays). Then I'd add the lists using `structure.NYSE.IBM.dateList = myDateList`, `structure.NYSE.securityList = mySecurityList`, and so on. It was fairly easy because Matlab lets you dynamically add and remove fields from structures as you please.

Comment: Thats an interesting syntax... essentially a tree-dictionary-type thing. A planned feature for Julia 0.4 is to make `.` an operator, so I could define a `MATLABStruct` type and then a method for `.` to allow that kind of thing.

Comment: Yes, I did read about that. In the end though I want to do this the "Julia way", rather than trying to emulate MatLab in Julia. Thanks again.